# HighChart with large amount of data(complex structure) not working

Tags: highcharts

I have a demo project to show inventory trends, and the inventory of each product is frequently, there may be hundreds of inventory points in one day. Now I need to show the inventory report of one week,a month and more, the problem comes out---I have two series, one line disappeared when the points come to neer 3000(not accurate);the chart displays nothing when the amout of data is large(such as 7000 points and more) completely!

The demo is here `CODE:`[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/skybreak/a5ngp6ja/8/), the format of datapoints are like the demo, error occures when the point number is large,such as 4000 and more, you can try to mock up large data of this demo to find the problem.

Actully I see million points of data shows fine in others' demo, then I tried to min the size of the data points but failed, the problem still exists.  How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) parameter, but for huge data we recommen to use Highstock which uses [dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) module, allowing to increase performance.